# One-to-many relationship Core Data : fetching in prepareForSegue:

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I've been tearing my hair out over the past few hours to try and figure out why this will not work. I have a one-to-many relationship in Core Data, and am trying to correctly pass the values to the detail segue.

Below is the datamodel (the attributes are binary data type):

[image]

If I fetch the data in the configureCell: method, it gives me the values as expected:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

self.everything = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSArray *arg = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everything.urls.urls];

NSLog (@"%@, [arg valueForKey:@"source"]); // this prints out a list of stored urls containing locations of jpeg images
}
```

My NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{ 
TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = nil;

fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;

entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Everything" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:INFINITY];

NSSortDescriptor *albumDescriptor = nil;

albumDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"album_names" ascending:NO];

NSSortDescriptor *urlDescriptor = nil;

urlDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"urls.urls" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = nil;

sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:albumDescriptor, urlDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = nil;

frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

[frc setDelegate:self];

[self setFetchedResultsController:frc];

return frc;

}
```

Here's my prepareForSegue: method. This part does not work. It crashes with an unrecognized selector error when I try and set the count of sections for the detail view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    self.everything = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everything.album_names];

    NSArray *urls = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everything.urls.urls];

    TBEverythingDetailViewController *details = segue.destinationViewController;

    details.everything = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"name"];

    self.urls.urls = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    details.everythingGroup = [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  
}
```

Part of the detail view controller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{

// This is where the actual crash happens. It complains about [_NSDictionaryM urls:] unrecognized selector sent to instance
NSArray *count = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everythingGroup.urls.urls];

return [count count]; 
}
```

I feel like I am missing some obvious step here as to why it's not working. Could I have any help?

Comment: Are you actually returning an NSFetchedResultsController from -fetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did set the details everythingGroup as:

```
NSArray *urls = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everything.urls.urls];
details.everythingGroup = [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

As I see in URLs.urls is an array of dictionaries archived into an NSData. So `details.everythingGroup` now is a dictionary, but you are accessing it so:

`NSArray *count = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.everythingGroup.urls.urls];`

It is normal that it's crashing here.
As you accessing it it looks like, that `details.everythingGroup` should be an `Everything`.

Answer (score 0):

Your self.everythinggrpup is an NSDictionary, and as such does not respond to a selector "urls". Somewher you are assiigning an NSDictionary instead of an Everything object to self.everythinggroup. So you need to not do that, or get the everything object out of that dictionary and then ask it for urls. Depends on how you've set this up.